# Properly structure path for rest API resources

Tags: rest

I am strucuring our rest API resources and came accross an interesting dilemma. Here is the scenario and I am going to use a car analogy

```
/cars/1/
{
   "id": 1,
   "make": "Toyota",
   "year_build": 2015
...
}

/cars/models/1/insurances
{
   "id": 1,
   insurances: [
{
   "policy_number": 101,
   "company": "Insurance Company 1",
   "valid_until": "2015-01-01"
},
{
   "policy_number": 102,
   "company": "Insurance Company 2",
   "valid_until": "2016-01-01"
}
]
...
}
```

I notice that resources can be reached with both
**/cars/1/insurances/102** and **/cars/1/insurances?policyid=102**, but **/cars/1/insurances/102** is more handier if we want to use additional subresources such as **/cars/1/insurances/102/agents/**....

My question really is do I have to follow the full path of url if each policy has a unique number, for example could i use

**/cars/insurances/102**

to get this policy instead of

**/cars/1/insurances?policyid=102**

Would take make a policy a primary resource instead of a car?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers -- they are opaque, from the point of view of the client, so the server can do whatever it likes.

There are conventions in play for URI design to make them more easily understood by human's.  See [Designing a REST API by URI vs query string](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/285724/199871).

> My question really is do I have to follow the full path of url if each policy has a unique number

If policies are unique entities in your model, then modeling each as an element in the policies collection is a reasonable thing to do: `/policies/104`

It's normal, in REST, to have multiple URI (therefore multiple resources) that share the same representation.  For instance, there might be a form that says "enter your policy number" which when submitted goes to `/policies?policyNumber=105` which could then either [redirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) the user to some other resource `/policies/105` or could present the content of the other resource (via [Content-Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.2)) or could present a representation of its own (which might duplicate the representations of other resources).

> URIs do NOT map onto domain objects - that violates encapsulation....  You should expect to have many many more resources in your integration domain than you do business objects in your business domain.  --Jim Webber, 2011.

Note that in REST, the expectation is that clients are negotiating your protocols by following hypermedia *links*.  If you aren't giving clients links to follow, but instead are making clients guess the next URL, then you should prioritize using a set of spellings that are consistent and easy to remember.

Yes, in particular when it's natural to think in terms of subresources, it's most convenient that the identifier is contained within the [hier-part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) of the URI.

Comment: So basically /cars/insurances/102 and /cars/1/insurances?policyid=102 could and up having different response despite the fact that that it is referencing the same domain object. Having consistent path structure should help when creating the response of the particular resource..

Comment: Yes. The first URI may retrieve a **collection of insurances with a single entry** instead of the insurance Itself

Comment: If you use queries, you are modifying / filtering the representantation of the resource. So, make sense to think that the Uri with query retrieve a collection (allways)

Comment: @Laiv we are not really discussing the use of queries here...

Comment: It was not my intention. Just explaining why the both URI may have different representantions. Due to the first use plural and filters It may lead to the think we are working with collection, so It make sense to expect a collection instead of a single object